# sorting of string with numbers in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I have strings like this:

```
"PQR23 on abc62", "PQR112 on efg7", "PQR9 on efg76" and so on
```

Now I would like to arrange this strings taking number in first character in ascending order.

so expected output should be

```
PQR112 on efg7
PQR23 on abc62
PQR9 on efg76
```

and so on

I am new to perl, doing homework and searching on net, but not received perfect soln so far.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? If you set `$a="PQR23 on abc62";` and `$b="PQR9 on efg76;`, can you create an expression that determines if `$a` should be before `$b`?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you want that a simple lexical sort doesn't provide. The program belows seems to do what you have specified.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings = (
  "PQR23 on abc62",
  "PQR112 on efg7", 
  "PQR9 on efg76",
);

print "$_\n" for sort @strings;
```

**output**

```
PQR112 on efg7
PQR23 on abc62
PQR9 on efg76
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to ignore the prefix letters, then a code block for sort will do the trick

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings = (
  "ABC23 on abc62",
  "PQR112 on efg7", 
  "XYZ9 on efg76",
);

print "$_\n"  for sort {
  my ($aa) = $a =~ /(\d)/;
  my ($bb) = $b =~ /(\d)/;
  $aa cmp $bb;
} @strings;
```

**output**

```
PQR112 on efg7
ABC23 on abc62
XYZ9 on efg76
```

Comment: This latter example is much shorter using List::UtilsBy:

    use List::UtilsBy qw( sort_by );

    print "$_\n" for sort_by { ( /(\d+)/ )[0] } @strings;

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [Schwartzian Transform](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col64.html) like that, very efficient if your array is big:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @strings = (
  "PQR23 on abc62",
  "PQR112 on efg7", 
  "PQR9 on efg76",
);

my @result = 
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]}
    map { [$_, /(\d)/] }
    @strings;

print Dumper\@result;
```

**output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'PQR112 on efg7',
          'PQR23 on abc62',
          'PQR9 on efg76'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @sorted_strings=sort("PQR23 on abc62", "PQR112 on efg7", "PQR9 on efg76");
print join ("\n",@sorted_strings);
```

Output

```
PQR112 on efg7
PQR23 on abc62
PQR9 on efg76
```